# Trying to add an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Im adding all the numbers between 0 and 1000 which are multiples or 3 and 5. Im just having trouble adding them up. I keep on getting the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 468, Size: 468

My Code

```
    //Multiple of 3 and 5 up to 1000
    int total = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> multof3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i =0; i <=1000; i++){

        if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5==0){
            multof3.add(i);
            total++;

        }else{
            continue;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(multof3);
    System.out.println(total);

    //looping through array to get sum of elements
    for(int x =0; x <= multof3.size(); x++){
        answer= answer + multof3.get(x);
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
```

Anyone know the reason why? I cant understand why its not working. It prints out the arraylist so surely I should add the elements together...

Comment: `x <= multof3.size()` -> `x < multof3.size()`

Comment: additional info You don't need use "continue;"  when you are already end of loop

Answer (score 3):

When looping through an array you have to keep in mind that it is indexed from 0.

```
  for(int x =0; x < multof3.size(); x++){
    answer= answer + multof3.get(x);
  }
```

If there are 468 items in the list then size() will return 468 but the last item is at index 467. Using the enhanced for loop can help avoid this type of problem:

```
  for(Integer i: multof3){
       answer += i;
  }
```

Comment: @Tloz, as soon as you got a solution, it would not hard to accept the answer by clicking tick mark right below the arrow button in the left: This is how stackoverflow works. In fact i can see from your profile that you are not an usual acceptor, which might provide bad impression to the answerer and they might avoid answering your question as most of their help is not being acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `for` condition `<=` to `<`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < multof3.size(); x++) {
    answer = answer + multof3.get(x);
}
```

Remember index starts in 0.

Answer (score 0):

which uses just `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(int x =0; x < multof3.size(); x++){
    answer= answer + multof3.get(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the element beyond the final one in the ArrayList. Change

`for(int x =0; x <= multof3.size(); x++){`

to

`for(int x =0; x < multof3.size(); x++){`